# How to set a state variable with react-router Route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

When a route matches, a component can be rendered, like:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Menu} />
```

but how can I add some action in the state variables? I tried:

```
<Route exact path='/' render={(props) => { this.state.screentitle = 'Menu'
                                           return (<Menu />) 
                                         }} />
```

but this does not work. So how can we do TWO things in a matching `<Route>`: do some javascript, and render the component?

The reason for this is that I want to select one of several 'screens', such as the menu page, or the update screen, or the search page, whatever. Also, in the header block of the app there is a screen title.

I tried also this:

```
<Route exact path='/' render={(props) => { this.setState({screentitle: 'Menu'}); return (<Menu />) }} />
```

but this gives a runtime warning: `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Comment: That does't work becasue you are  directly changing the state with out any `setState` & I don't think that doing setstate in render of route is advisable, it may trigger infinite rerenders

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty won't I get an infinite loop when I call setState in render()?

Comment: @Ronald, Thats what i said, but thats the purpose of maintaining state, Please explain clearly what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can use react's context API's to set `screentitle`. Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api).

Using react Context you can share data between components i.e. `Menu` component and user parent component. 
You need not perform state change in the `Route` render function, just update the Context once you navigate to the `Menu` component.

If You want the parent itself to handle `screentitle` you can use the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
  this.onRouteChanged();
 }
}
```

`onRouteChanged` can contain your logic to set `screentitle`.

Comment: React Context surely looks interesting, but here I don't need to share the screentitle with the component selected by the Route. The main App should display a screen title related to the matched Route, and render the selected component, independently.

Comment: Then, onRouteChanged should contain duplicate Route elements to set the title according to the URL. Duplicate stuff is not nice. Also, that Route should not render a component, but set a state variable; ok, this problem can be solved to render a ScreenTitle component and pass it a screentitle string property. Anyway, this makes me feel the entire react-router pretty cumbersome; why not just forget about the URL and simply switch screens based on a state variable instead?